# ¿Cuál es el equivalente de este código PHP en ASP.Net?

Tags: php, asp.net

Necesito saber cuál es el equivalente de este código PHP en ASP.Net (con C#) y no se cómo hacerlo. ¿Alguien me puede indicar cómo se haría?

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST)) 
    {

    $array_resp = $_POST['row'];


    print_r($array_resp);

    }


?>
```

Comment: Que necesitas traducir? a VB o C# ?

Comment: en asp.net trabjas con evento, en que accion pondrias ese codigo ? en el Page_Load, en el click de un boton.  Porque defines el valor que tomas del POST como un array si parece ser que solo tomas un valor 'row'

Comment: en el page_load y los datos que van a enviar son 
$array_resp[0] = array( 
   'cel' => '1156637157',
   'nom' => 'Juan',
   'dato' => 'DF97',
   'men' => 'Texto de la respuesta'
   'hora' => '12:56:02 18/03/13'
  );

Comment: Hola, hice una edición con la cual creo que la pregunta es mas clara y podría ser re abierta.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

La conversion podria ser algo como

```
public void Page_Load(..){

    if(!IsPostBack){

       string resp = Request.Form["row"].ToString();

       Console.Write(resp);

    }

}
```

El `isset` no tiene equivalente en .net

Ademas estas tomando un valor unico del post, no se porque a la variable la defines como `$array_resp`  a los umo seri `$resp`

saludos

Comment: Gracias Leandro, y el array seria asi:
'cel' => '1156637157',
'nom' => 'Juan',
'dato' => 'DF97',
'men' => 'Texto de la respuesta',
'hora' => '12:56:02 18/03/13' );

Comment: @NicolasAlbertoQuinteros  pero en que objeto de asp.net armarias un array para envielo por post ? porque desde la UI del usuario no se puede armar un array de esa forma. Salvo que desde codigo .net armes el array y lo pongas en el objeto Session

Comment: el tema es asi, a mi me van a postear el array y yo lo tengo que guardar en la base. el tema es que no se como hacerlo. o sea me pasaron ese codigo de ejemplo y nada mas y como nunca trabaje con esta tecnologia no se por donde empezar ni nada

Comment: si el array va a llegar po post entonces el objeto que debes usar es el que menciono Request.Form, podrias en el Page_Load poner un breakpoint inspeccionarlo las keys que el lleguen y ver como se serializa el array

Comment: Muchas gracias Leandro

Comment: no entiendo como funciona stackoverflow en español, la respuesta se marca como repsuesta pero se pone en espera, si ya se le dio una solucion porque se la ponen en espera? se marca una respuesta que soluciono el problema pero se vota en negativo, como es eso si la respuesta ayudo? no tiene sentido la logica aplicada en la administracion, se hace cualquier cosa

Comment: vamos por un +1, no tiene sentido que ande negativo

Answer (score 1):

Esta utilidad de conversión no traducirá todo, pero ahorrará un montón de tiempo para la migración de PHP a ASP.

http://www.me-u.com/php-asp/

Answer (score 1):

Como complemento, aunque :

```
(isset($_POST))
```

sería algo como:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["POST"])
```

yo lo traduciria como:

```
if((HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")){    
   string array_resp = Request.Form["row"].ToString();    
   Console.Write(array_resp);    
}
```

Comment: ¿No debería ser `String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["row"])`?

Comment: No, porque en este caso es validar si se realizo un POST, la "traducción" correcta sería como lo indica Leandro: !IsPostBack.

Comment: Cierto. Leí mal el código del OP. Para mí es extraño usar algo como `isset($_POST)` en PHP, lo mejor sería validar si el parámetro existe. En fin, cosas de locos.

Comment: Creo que `isset($_POST)` se podría traducir mejor como `Request.HttpMethod == "POST"`. Por otro lado, en `asp.net` no pasaría nada por usar `Request.Form["row"]` directamente porque devolvería cadena vacía. Personalmente me parece una locura pretender traducir `php` a `asp.net`de esta manera y creo que falta contexto para poder dar una respuesta adecuada /cc  @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: Tienes razón rsiciriano, tiene más sentido : if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "POST") { ...

Comment: @Elenasys El `.ToString()` no creo que devuelva algo parecido a [`print_r();`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.print-r.php). Lo primero porque en `Request.Form["row"]` no hay un `array` (que es posible que sea lo que haya en `php`) sino que hay un `string`. Vamos, que la conversión no es tan directa, aunque si es posible.